# Make depth-stencil buffer to be in `GL_DEPTH32F_STENCIL8` format

Tags: opengl-es, gles

I have a code that makes depth-stencil buffer to be in `GL_DEPTH32F_STENCIL8` format with some offscreen render buffer:

```
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &rboDepthStencil);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rboDepthStencil);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH32F_STENCIL8, Width, Height);
```

how to do the same with the regular (or default) render buffer?